# JUNIT says empty list is null. How to set arr[0] to "" using generic type?

Tags: java, junit

I have the following code:

```
public String toString()
  {
    String returnValue = String.valueOf(arr[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      if(size == 0)
      {
         returnValue = returnValue + "";
      }
      else
      {
         returnValue = returnValue + ", " + arr[i];
      }
    }
    return returnValue;
  }
```

And the following JUNIT test:

```
@Test
  public void testToString()
  {
    GenericList<String> b = new GenericList<String>();
    assertEquals("", b.toString());
    b.add("hello");
    assertEquals("hello", b.toString());
    b.add("bye");
    assertEquals("hello, bye", b.toString());
    b.add("adios");
    assertEquals("hello, bye, adios", b.toString());
  }
```

When running JUnit, I get an error:

expected:<[]> but was:<[null]>

I have tried a variety of different methods to fix this, but I cannot seem to get it. How can I adjust my code to pass the JUnit test? That is, how can I get the first index of the array to equal and empty string ""?

The array is created with a generic type, and can't be set. Meanwhile, when an array is created like in the test, it will be 0 in size, holding a null value. I cannot simply set the null value to "" because its type generic.

Thank you all.

Comment: `arr[0]` is null, and size <= 0, apparently.

Comment: `if(size == 0)` the body would never be executed. Maybe you mean `i == 0`; but then `returnValue = returnValue + "";` is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial way to pass this failing assertion is to return if the list is empty:

```
if (size == 0) return "";
```

You are currently prepending the first element of the array to the string, even if that element's value isn't part of the list.

You also have the problem that the first element of the list will be included twice, because the loop starts at 0, not 1. And the `if (size == 0)` is redundant, because it will never be true.

An easier way to implement the whole method is:

```
return String.join(", ", Arrays.asList(arr).subList(0, size));
```